# How to draggable button background color to apply another button background?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How to apply one button background color to another button background color when I drag. Example, if I have multiple buttons, in that one was red color and all other are white. So when I drag the yellow color button to another button on side, it will need to change as yellow color. The old one should be white. I have tried in many ways using jQuery and CSS, but I could not get a solution for this work. Below I have attached my screen. Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<td><button id="table-<?php echo $tables->id; ?>" type="button" value="<?php echo $tables->id; ?>" class="table-<?php echo $tables->id; ?>" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragenter="dragEnter(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" <?php foreach($table_selected as $sel){ if($sel->tableid==$tables->id){ if($sel->table_type=='1'){ ?> ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget" style="background-color:yellow;border: 1px yellow;width:170px;height:50px;" onClick="javascript:location.href ='index.php?module=pos&amp;reserved_id=<?php echo $sel->id; ?>'" <?php }elseif($sel->table_type=='2'){ ?> onClick="javascript:location.href ='index.php?module=pos&amp;reserved_id=<?php echo $sel->id; ?>'" style="background-color:green;border: 1px green;width:170px;height:50px;" <?php } } } ?> style="width:170px;height:50px;" name="<?php echo $tables->table_name; ?>"><span><span><?php echo $tables->table_name; ?></span></span></button></td>
```

The script given below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}

function dragEnter(event) {
    if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Entered the dropzone";
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
}

function dragLeave(event) {
    if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Left the dropzone";
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
}

function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you write a code ? If yes, post it

Comment: For dragging color code or table list code. i have tried for draggable , but it not working.

Comment: And post it even if it doesn't work, so someone can help you

Comment: ya ok. i'll post that code now.

Comment: i have refereed the drag code in this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_ondrag_all

Comment: Have you tried to solve your problem with the provided code?

Comment: ya tried. but cant get my need exactly. i need like interchange the colors. if i drag yellow to white means, it need to interchange the colors only. But my code not work like that.

Comment: I have generated the table buttons are dynamically and apply the colors in the some conditions based. Here i have post the button code and drag scripts only.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle? 
And the generated html + css?

Comment: ok sure. i'll put and give a link...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jaganakash/r7v4jepn/6/ this is fiddle link . Here i need 102 to 104 interchange colors when i drag.